# Can AMP be used as both mobile and desktop versions?

Tags: amp-html

I didn't find a straight answer on that anywhere as it clearly says in the name (AMP) itself too, that it's used for a static mobile web pages.

I found out that `amp` tag is used on desktop version like for example  [ampproject.org](https://www.ampproject.org/) has

So it's unclear to me now whether the AMP can (*is benefitial to*) be used on desktop version as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible, your site is going to work well on both Desktop and Mobile devices, it's going to load properly and work really fast.

BUT, keep in mind that **AMP** is more oriented toward mobile devices, all of the current libraries that you can use are definitely focused in creating a faster experience on small devices, and some of the mayor sites implementing AMP are using different version, like Mobile, Desktop and AMP version of each page or article, sounds complicated to maintain, but it allows to offer the best experience for each user on every device.

So, if you want to create a cross device site from start, AMP is a good option, just keep in mind that a bunch of the things you see on other sites (interaction plugins, javascript libraries, complex ajax functionality, complex forms and validations) are not currently supported, maybe in the future, maybe not.

Comment: Thanks for heads up @camilo_u

Comment: but we can't access www.google.com/amp/www.domain.com from desktop

Answer (score 20):

I have created a completely new AMP-only website from scratch, and after around 6 months it is well indexed in Google search engine and getting consistent traffic. It works perfectly on all platforms - Mobile, Desktop as well as Tablets.
(*By AMP-only website, I mean there is only one version which is AMP. There is no other separate version for desktop, and the same AMP version is shown on all devices.*)

However, after months of hard-work, I found the following shortcomings with this AMP-only approach:

1. A lot of functionality and features are unavailable in AMP (like those which can be easily accomplished through JavaScript), and we have to make a lot of compromises which takes a toll on end-user experience.
2. Even simple looking features which can be easily implemented in a non-AMP site (like form submissions) needs a lot of work to make them AMP-compatible and still the desired may not be accomplished fully.
3. Worst of the lot is when it comes to **monetization**. I was under the impression that since AMP is Google-supported, adsense implementation will be a cake-walk. But got a nasty surprise!

3.1) Google's **AMP AUTO ads** don't work at all. There is absolutely no help available either from Google, its official forums, or anywhere on the net. (Just do a Google Search on "AMP Auto Ads not working" and see if you can spot even a single solution. There are only questions and repeated AMP code snippets which don't work.)

3.2) Google's **AMP ads** (non-auto ones) also work highly erratically. They **don't** show up when the site is accessed on a Desktop, and they display **only on mobile devices**. Its a big loss of revenue for the publisher, despite Google's claim that these ads show seamlessly on all devices! Once in a bluemoon, they may be visible on desktop, but 90% of the times they are not.

3.3) If you try to use other ads (non-Google Adsense), then you will find that most of the ad agencies don't offer AMP-compatible ad display code. Almost all have Javascript code which is non-AMP. So if you use them, AMP benefits go away. At the end, you are solely tied to Google Ads which themselves may/may-not work.

So to summarize the answer to your question ("*Can AMP be used as both mobile and desktop versions?*") - Yes, it can be, and your site can be well indexed in Google.

But (and its a big but), if you are planning to monetize your site through ads (Google or others), or if you want to give a proper end-user experience to your site visitors, then better to have two separate versions. It appears that AMP remains a Google work-in-progress with loads and loads of issues. It's the publishers who work hard and end up disappointed, so better keep multiple versions.

**Above all, there is no help available from anywhere - not even Google. I learnt it the hard way. This question was raised in 2016, and even in 2020 AMP remains a challenge.**

***Update as of May 2021:***

It is better to completely ditch AMP.

AMP is for accelerated mobile pages - i.e.- they are fast pages that are suppose to load quickly on mobile. AMP was launched at a time when mobile networks were slow, and net companies (including Google) were looking for speedy pages that load quickly on mobiles (and their then slow networks).

Fast forward to 2021, 4G and 5G mobile data services are now readily being available across the globe. Now, the benefits of AMP are no longer worth the restrictions AMP imposes.

Each page, whether bulky or light, still loads easily on mobiles because high speed net access is now available on 4G/5G.

So avoid taking a deep and big cut in your site functionality while complying with AMP.

Instead, go for a fully-functional non-AMP website, and keep your site users happy by offering them full functionality (not restricted by AMP).

Thanks!

Comment: You’re right. When there came to more complicated things like forms where I needed do some manipulations and vanilla JS or jQuery would strip off a lot of work, I didn’t use AMP at all. Page was more dynamic then static. So mostly I used AMP on static pages. I think AMP is meant to be used for mobile pages only If you need all features to be working as stated in docs. Otherwise you end up with AMP JS scripts on desktop version you don’t need and can build it much more simpler way without it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!, I was adding AMP to my site and because of my OCD I made it work for desktop aswell and was wondering if I could make it cross device since they keep adding more and more components, iFrames, etc. but I had this big doubt about Ads! which at least for me es too important

Comment: @Aquaholic How about now in July 2020, are your problem solved? for small business, I think AMP more suitable to Landing Page by selling product other than become publisher (news/blog/etc)...

Comment: @coderInrRain Its complicated. (1) Ur thought is right to have landing AMP pages, but do remember Google is much smarter. It looks at the overall site instead of only a few (landing) pages. (2) Also, if you want the landing pages as AMP, then you are depriving ur site customers of other features and functionality (which is not supported by AMP). Nowadays, users expect all easy features to be available to have a good shopping experience. But since they are not supported by AMP, it makes a site user completely go off. A simple form submission is a big pain in AMP. So, better go for non-AMP.

Comment: @Aquaholic no it's not complicated. For me, Landing Page just to get leads. just image link that redirects to Whatsapp is enough. I get sales/conversion from there. but if you mean complete eCommerce web than we should stay away from AMP but use wordpress+woocommerce. about google smarter, just create 1 landing page = 1 domain name, also it's purpose not for SEO only.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is possible to use AMP in web or what you said desktop. The purpose of AMP is for creating fast-loading mobile web pages, but this is not mean that it is only limited for the mobile.

If you also check the Supporter browsers part in this [Github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/DEVELOPING.md#supported-browsers), It is stated that:

> In general, we support the 2 latest versions of major browsers like
>   Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari and Opera. We support **desktop**, phone,
>   tablet and the web view version of these respective browsers.
>
> Beyond that the core AMP library and built-in elements should aim for
>   very wide browser support and we accept fixes for all browsers with
>   market share greater than 1 percent.

For more information about AMP, check this [page](http://searchengineland.com/get-started-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp-240688) and the link that you provide in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I think that too and I've read that too. It's just confuses me that folks beyond AMP talk about mobile use only whereas it has a potential in desktop use. So the only benefit to get out of AMP for desktop version is speed...I presume.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we used AMP only for our entire website. It's fast and it ranks decently well too.

Meaning, if you're ever looking for any AMP WordPress guides check this [resource](https://wpza.net/accelerated-mobile-pages/) out as we've covered all the steps you need to AMP any website (…way too long to post here).

Comment: @coderInrRain in general, yes because it seems to rank better. However, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798066/4968696) for more guidance on IF you should use it.