# AMP Desktop Compatibility

Tags: amp-html

This is an extension of [Can AMP be used as both mobile and desktop versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056800/can-amp-be-used-as-both-mobile-and-desktop-versions)

---

I would like to build a (simple) microsite using AMP. The same site should also work on Desktops as well.

Since AMP is developed and meant for Mobile devices (with a higher standard), I was wondering what the best way is to approach this.

1. Is there a compatibility list of which features are also working on desktops?
2. Are there fallback options for desktop users with non-modern browsers?
3. Is there even a desktop-mode which AMP can run in?

---

### Example

To illustrate that it might be a real problem, here is a screenshot of https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/about-amp.html with IE11:
[image]

You can clearly see that the YouTube video renders way too big in width and height for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMP team member here.

AMP is definitely not exclusive to Mobile. Both the AMP website and my own ([paulbakaus.com](https://paulbakaus.com)) showcase this clearly.

The above screenshot looks like a bug – all components should work across Mobile and Desktop (and everything inbetween, provided you're using the last two versions of a popular browser). Please file any bugs you find at https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I'll file a bug report. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works on desktop. If you go to the [AMP Project homepage](https://ampproject.org) on a desktop, you'll see that it is an AMP page and works perfectly. If you open their demo pages on a desktop, they will work perfectly as well.

Comment: Well, that depends on which browser you use. Try open it for example with IE11 (which is still quite popular) - I attached a screenshot in my question

Comment: Oh, I'm a Mac user so I didn't get a chance to try it in IE. And AMP isn't really intended to be used with IE since it's not available for mobile devices. But I think so server side logic with the user agent would fix that issue.

Comment: No worries, I think I just got my answer anyway - AMP should only be used for mobile websites and not for a broad desktop audience.